# creates a Debian binary package, a .deb file from cx_Freeze-d Python executables

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, cx-freeze, deb

After freezing my python scripts into executables via cx_Freeze, I wonder how to package this executables into a debian binary package, a .deb file. Any ideas?

Comment: Normally if you want to build a .deb package you wouldn't freeze it first, but rather make the package depend on Python.

Comment: @ThomasK include the Python scripts into a .deb package? What if I want to distribute closed source Python software ?

Comment: cx_Freeze makes it a bit harder to see your source code, but it's still quite possible.